# Boolean inside SELECT - help needed

Tags: sql, boolean

[image]

I need to write a SQL query to get the department name and the number of female professors in that department even if there aren't any female professors hired there. Please help. Thank you.

| STUDENT |
| --- |
| id |
| first_name |
| last_name |
| is_female |
| department_id |

| DEPARTMENT |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| PROFESSOR |
| --- |
| id |
| first_name |
| last_name |
| is_female |
| department_id |

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    department.name, COUNT(professor.is_female) 
FROM 
    department, professor
WHERE 
    department.id = professor.department_id
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please include the information here instead of linking it externally, and share a query so we can help you debug it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am new here and they don't allowe me to embed images in my posts yet so they included a link instead. I will try to edit it and provide more info.

Comment: You want to share a text (data and query) with us not images.

Comment: I've shared the query but not sure how to include female professors even if they are not hired

Comment: **Bad habits to kick** : [using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks marc_s37 for your input. Still not sure how to include female professors even if they are not hired. Got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you included the student table but try either this correlated sub-query:

```
select name, (select count(*) from PROFESSOR where DEPARTMENT.id = PROFESSOR.department_id and is_female = true) as 'count'
from DEPARTMENT
```

or left-join:

```
select name, count(*)
from DEPARTMENT
left join PROFESSOR on DEPARTMENT.id = PROFESSOR.department_id and is_female = true
group by 1
```

Comment: That solves the issue. Thanks a lot for your help.